# Appending sas tables with different types of varibles (Character on the base, numeric on the data)

Tags: sas, append, concatenation, proc

I'm trying to append tables in sas where in the first table (table_1) the type of (id_1,id_2,id_3) is characters :

```
+------+------+------+--------------+--+
| id_1 | id_2 | id_3 |     date     |  |
+------+------+------+--------------+--+
|    1 |   14 |    5 |  25/06/2010  |  |
|    2 |   10 |    4 |  25/06/2014  |  |
+------+------+------+--------------+--+
```

and the type of columns (id_1,id_2,id_3) in other tables can be numeric or charcters or both at the same time.

```
+------+------+------+--------------+--+
| id_1 | id_2 | id_3 |     date     |  |
+------+------+------+--------------+--+
|    3 |    7 |    3 |  25/06/2017  |  |
|    4 |   11 |    9 |  25/06/2020  |  |
+------+------+------+--------------+--+
```

With this proc :

```
proc append base=table_1 data=table_X force ;
run;
```

if the type of the colum is numeric i had a missing values as a result

I want to write a generic code who convert automatically the type of data to characters if it's numeric.

Is there a solution to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Should the order be preserved? Should the result replace table_1, or is it ok to create `table_both`?

Comment: Why not fix how the tables are defined to begin with so that they are all defined consistently? How were TABLE_2, TABLE_3 , etc created?

Answer (score 1):

The variables named `ID_<#>` must all be the same type in both tables.  You can convert numeric values to character values using `PUT` function or `CATS` function.

```
data table2_char_ids;
  set table2(rename=(id_1-id_3=numid1-numid3));
  array numids numid1-numid3;
  length id_1-id_3 $8;
  array ids id_1-id_3;
  do index = 1 to dim(numids);
    ids(index) = cats(numids(index));
  end;
  drop  numid1-numid3;
run;

proc append base=data_1 data=table2_char_ids force;
run;
```

Comment: the problem in this case is when in "table 2" there is two columns numeric and the third is character i will have an error, because i want to do a generic code so that it doesn't matter the type of the columns in the second table when i do the append he read it automatically as a character !

Comment: You should have told us your example is just an example and explained the general problem in your original question.

Comment: Do you want to convert every non compatible variable to character or to the type it has in `table_1`?

Comment: I just edit my question sorry to not be enough clear ! yes exactly

Answer (score 1):

First convert the data

```
data view_2 / view = view_2;
```

while reading in the data, rename the alphabetic id's

```
    set table_2 (rename=(id_1 = old_1 id_2 = old_2 id_3 = old_3));
```

write out the numeric id's as digits

```
    id_1 = put(old_1, 8.);
    id_2 = put(old_2, 8.);
    id_3 = put(old_3, 8.);
```

remove the numerci id's from the result (the colon is a wild card)

```
    drop old_:;
```

and proceed

```
run;
```

proc append force
base=table_1
data=view_2 ;
run;

note that I added `/ view = view_2` to create a view instaid of a table, just to avoid reading and writing a huge dataset to disk once more